# Show user that the form was submitted successful or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have a form which sends data to a CRM. If I create a simple HTML form and send the data to the server it will refresh my webpage and show the text:

```
{"success":false,"error":{"message":"<whatever the error is>"}}
```

or

```
{"success":true,"result":"ok"}
```

After styling the form and integrating animations and validations and stuff everything still works perfectly. Now the data is sent by using http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started. The server receives it but the user has no idea whether it did or not.

Using this jQuery form plugin or some other plugin you might want me to use(or even code) please help me display text inside a div whether the operation was successful or not, depending on the server's response.

I have only tried to display the response using the examples provided here: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm but I have failed until now.

Here I've put together a JSfiddle with some form fields and the jQuery form plugin I am using in order to send the data to the server: http://jsfiddle.net/n78p9/1/.

I hope someone will be able to show me what I did wrong or show me another way of doing this.

Thank you!

EDIT @Arun: so it looks like this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            target: '.optional',
            resetForm: true,
            success: function(responseText){
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
                if(!result.success){
                    alert(result.error.message)
               }
          },
          error: function(){
             alert('Thank you for your message! Our team will contact you in the shortest possible time.')
          }
        }); 
    }
```

I am definitely on the right way, but there is a problem: the error alert actually shows when the response is successful. I do not understand why. I have intercepted the POST request through a local proxy and re-sent it through the server and the server sent back this:

```
{"success":true,"result":"ok"}
```

But the script considered it an error. That is why I have inserted that text into the error:alert field:D.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Use the success and error callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [callbacks](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object) provided by the library

```
    var options = {
        target: '#response',
        success: showResponse,
        clearForm: true,
        success: function(responseText){
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
            if(!result.success){
                alert(result.error.message)
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('some error')
        }
    };
    $('#contact-form').ajaxForm(options);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It helped me to get on the right track. I integrated your fix into the validation function and now it looks like this(edit in the question):

Comment: I added the code in the question along with some more information. Please take a look when you have some spare time. Thank you!

Comment: @user2047678 the response status should be 200

Comment: well, it seems that the response is 200 OK for both success:true and success:false. I do not know how to handle it. What else can be done?